# Failed to write to file but generates no Error

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to write to a file but it's not working. I've gone through step-by-step with the debugger (it goes to the write command but when I open the file it's empty).

My question is either: "How do I see what the error is so I can debug?", "What can go wrong when trying to write to a file that would cause it to behave this way?".

```
sqlScript = open('script-file.sql', 'a')

    try:
         sqlScript.write(sqlLine)
    except IOError as (errno, strerror):
         print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
```

This should be simple but I can't seem to find an answer. Also, I apologize in advance as English is a second language.

Edit: I put a print statement just before and the string is not empty.

Edit2: I'm using python 2.6 if that factors in somehow.

Edit 3: I've found a "solution" to my error. I decided to try and run my script using IDLE instead of PyCharm and it works like a charm (pun intended). I have no clue why, but there it is. Any reason why that would happen?!

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Does it generate the exception you're catching? Or is no exception generated?

Comment: Did you close or flush the file in the Python process prior to inspecting it?

Comment: Alan: It doesn't generate an error.
Larsmans: I only open it to append.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Given the wrong indentation, I suspect not and that something else is affecting it. Have you tried running your code exactly as it is posted here (set sqlLine a value yourself)? It could be the problem lies elsewhere. You should also look into [the ``with`` statement](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for writing files (``with open('script-file.sql', 'a') as sqlScript:``).

Comment: It's the actual code (only I changed the file name since it's a client's name.) It didn't keep my indentation when I copied it over so I put spaces myself.

Answer (score 4):

Building on Chris Morris' answer, maybe do something like this:

```
try:
    sqlScript.write(sqlLine)
except Exception as e:
    print type(e)
    print str(e)
```

This will catch any Exception thrown (provided it's a subclass of `Exception`, of course) and tell you the type and the error message.

Also, it's possible to define multiple `except:` cases for different possible exceptions, so maybe try doing that for each exception that might be potentially thrown/raised.

Answer (score 2):

The following code allows you to see what exception it is that is being thrown, and see a trace of where it originated from.

```
try:
    sqlScript.write(sqlLine)
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise
```

See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html for more info.

Comment: I used your code and I don't get an error. It's really strange.

Comment: @Boona Are you sure? That seems pretty weird. No 'unexpected error' messages pops up on your console?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your cursor at the beginning of the file. You can do that with `seek` method:

```
myScript.seek(0)
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2949648/2119117

Answer (score 0):

If no exception is being tossed, I'd suspect the string variable 'sqlLine' is empty.

Did you print it before the write statement?

Comment: I put a print statement just before and the string is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Are the keywords in the script in lowercase? The same thing happened to me in another db and I solved it by changing words to UPPERCASE.

Comment: I don't even get a chance to run the script since I can't write it to the file. :P (Note: I'm not writing directly to the DB but generating a script that will be run at a later date.)

Comment: I just found the issue. When I tried running it with IDLE instead of PyCharm it worked. I have no idea why. :P

Answer (score 0):

Your current working directory isn't what you expect it to be and it's successfully writing to some `script-file.sql` in another directory. Try printing `os.getcwd()` and make sure it's what you expect, and look in that directory.

Comment: Interesting! I checked and it's the directory I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

It happened on my linux environment but work on windows try

```
sqlScript = open('script-file.sql', 'a', buffering=False)
```

or

```
sqlScript = open('script-file.sql', 'a', 0)
```